# Soma de coluna do DatagridView incorreta

Tags: c#, winforms

Quando clico no botão buscar através de uma data especifica no primeiro momento a soma é realizada de forma correta. Quando altero a data e busco novamente ele soma com a anterior. Estou utilizando `Foreach` para percorrer e somar todas as coluna do `índice` conforme exemplo:

```
private void BuscarData()
{

    this.dataLista.DataSource = Nvenda.BuscarData(this.dtInicial.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), this.dtFinal.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));

    this.ocultarColunas();
    lblTotal.Text = "Total de Registros: " + Convert.ToString(dataLista.Rows.Count);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dataLista.Rows)
    {
        total += Convert.ToDecimal(linha.Cells[10].Value);

    }
    lblVendaTotal.Text = total.ToString("R$ #0.00#");
}
```

Comment: se entendi bem a sua pergunta, não seria o caso de resetar o valor da variável `total`  toda vez que seja efetuada uma busca? Por esse trecho parecesse que essa variável está em um escopo global, por isso está armazenando as informações anteriores.

Comment: William, Isso mesmo! A variável total está como global. Poderia me dizer como faço para esta variável não ficar pegando o valor anterior? Pois toda vez que atualizo a grid com outro período ele soma com o valor anterior.. Muito obrigado!

Comment: tem algum motivo para ela ser global? Já tentou declarar ela no seu método `BuscarData()`? Você pode deixar `global` e zerar ela no inicio do `BuscarData` assim sempre que executar esse método a variável `total` irá sempre estar vazia.

Comment: Declarei a variável como Local, deu certo! Obrigado Willian!